# Lombok the getter or setter not working Spring Boot on Mac

Tags: java, spring-boot, eclipse, lombok

I am using Spring Boot in Eclipse and Lombok is installing in my project, but still can not make setter and getter.

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class AddCourseDto {
    private int tool;
}
```

Second class

```java
public class CourseDto {
    
    private final AddCourseDto course2;
    
    public CourseDto(AddCourseDto course2) {
         this.course2=course2;
    }

    public int getname() {
        return course2.getTool(); // here the getTool() does not work 
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share the pom.xml file

Comment: You probably don't back l have Lombok installed in your eclipse. Just adding it to the POM isn't enough.

Comment: `<dependency>
   <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
   <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
   <optional>true</optional>
  </dependency>  <configuration>
     <excludes>
      <exclude>
       <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
       <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      </exclude>
     </excludes>
    </configuration>` ** this from Lombok file all about the package ** @Janil101 @Jan Rieke

Comment: @JanRieke this my pom.xml

Comment: @Janil101 this all about Lombok pom.xml

Comment: Check whether you have correctly installed the Lombok eclipse plugin: https://projectlombok.org/setup/eclipse